# Unexpected behaviour of SO_SNDTIMEO and SO_RCVTIMEO

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm trying to set the timeout for the blocking TCP socket on Linux using `setsockopt` with `SO_SNDTIMEO` and `SO_RCVTIMEO`. But for some reason I get a lock while waiting on `recv` call.

Consider the minimal example. I've shortened it a bit for readability, the full code is available in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jubnzv/93d7f1f3e334552fcb6cd01aedfee93b). I create a server socket and set the timeouts using `setsockopt`. Next, the server exchanges messages with the client. After a while, the client interrupts data exchange and closes the socket. But the server still waiting in blocking `recv`. However, I expect it to abort `recv` when the timeout expires.

Network functions used by the client and server:

```c
int set_timeout(int fd, int sec) {
  struct timeval timeout;
  timeout.tv_sec = sec;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;

  if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout,
                 sizeof(timeout)) < 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout,
                 sizeof(timeout)) < 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int blocking_recv(int sock, char *data, size_t size) {
  size_t remain_data = size;
  ssize_t recv_nb;
  int offset = 0;

  while ((remain_data > 0) &&
         ((recv_nb = recv(sock, data + offset, remain_data, 0)) >= 0)) {
    remain_data -= recv_nb;
    offset += recv_nb;
  }
  if (recv_nb == -1 || remain_data > 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int blocking_send(int sock, char *buf, size_t size) {
  size_t total = 0;
  int remain = size;
  int n;

  while (total < size) {
    n = send(sock, buf + total, remain, 0);
    if (n == -1) {
      break;
    }
    total += n;
    remain -= n;
  }

  return (total == size) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

Server:

```c
while (1) {
  struct sockaddr_in caddr;
  size_t len = sizeof(caddr);
  if ((client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&caddr, (socklen_t *)&len)) < 0) {
    continue;
  }

  // Set 3 seconds timeout using SO_{SND,RCV}TIMEO
  if (set_timeout(client_fd, 3) != 0) {
    continue;
  }

  // Send and receive data in the loop. We assume that the client is stuck,
  // we'll break the connection using a timeout.
  while (1) {
    char in_data[data_size];
    char *out_data = "test\0";
    if (blocking_recv(client_fd, in_data, data_size) != 0)
      break;
    if (blocking_send(client_fd, out_data, data_size) != 0)
      break;
  }
}
```

Client:

```c
int attempts_left = 5;
while (--attempts_left > 0) {
  char in_data[6];
  char *out_data = "test\0";
  if (blocking_send(fd, out_data, 6) != 0)
    break;
  if (blocking_recv(fd, in_data, 6) != 0)
    break;
  sleep(1);
}

close(fd);
```

What could be wrong?

Is it possible to implement the timeout for `recv` in this way, without using `select`, `poll` and signals?

Thanks!

Comment: `((recv_nb = recv(sock, data + offset, remain_data, 0)) >= 0)` Well, you never quit, so... you just loop.

Comment: @KamilCuk ah, you're right, it was stupid. Sorry for this noise. I can accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: FWIW, the timeout doesn't come into play here... when the client closes the socket the server gets notified (it creates basically an EOF condition) without any wait required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping your reading:

```
while ((remain_data > 0) &&
         ((recv_nb = recv(sock, data + offset, remain_data, 0)) >= 0)) {
    remain_data -= recv_nb;
    offset += recv_nb;
  }
```

yet `read` from `man read` returns:

```
 If no messages are available to be received and the peer has
   performed an orderly shutdown, recv() shall return 0.
```

So you are just looping endlessly.

You should correctly handle `errno` in your program. when `SNDTIMEO` stuff timeouts, you get: `the timeout has been reached then -1 is returned with errno set to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK, or EINPROGRESS (for connect(2)) ...`.

Still `EAGAIN` can be returned when signal interrupts, so just the usual `select()` or `poll()` for 3 seconds would be probably simpler. If not, measure time yourself anyway and set the timeout to the max timeout you want and measure how much time has passed. Along:

```
timeout = now + 3 seconds.
// check timeout yourself
while (timeout_not_expired(&timeout)) {
   // set timeout for the __next__ recv operation
   set_recv_timeout(timeout_to_expire(&timeout));
   ret = recv();
   if (ret == -1 && errno == EAGAIN) {
      continue;
   }
   if (ret == -1) {
        /* handle errror */
   }
   if (ret == 0) {
      /* closed */
   }
   /* actually received stuff */
}
```

Use tools like `strace` and a debugger to debug your programs.